# Excel to get greater result from a sum of 2 columns

Tags: microsoft-excel

Hi,

I have a spreadsheet with soccer results. Each one represented by 2 columns. One column shows the goals for and the other one shows the goals against. The table on sheet 1 would look like this:

```
             GF GA           GF GA       GF GA

             Team A          Team B     Team C  
2001        0   - 12         0  - 9      0  - 6
2002        1   - 5          1  - 1      0  - 4
2003        1   - 11         2  - 8      0  - 5
2004        4   - 1          0  - 6      1  - 6
2005        1   - 6          1  - 6      1  - 5 
2006        0   - 5          1  - 7      0  - 7
```

============================

Based on the results above, the table on sheet 2 which is what I am trying to achieve here should look like this:

```
             TGF TGA  GD    BR     WR
Team A        7  40   -33   4-1   0-12
Team B        5  37   -32   1-1   0-9
Team C        2  33   -31   0-4   0-7

TGF = Total Goals For
TGA = Total Goals Against
GD = Goal Difference
BR = Best Result
WR = Worst Result
```

I already got the first 3 columns right but I cant figure out how to do the other 2. The best result column and the worst result one are based on the goal difference of that match. Please notice Best Result wont always mean a victory because whereas the best result for Team A was a 4-1 win the best result for Team B is just a 1-1 tie and as for Team C the "best" they got is a 0-4 loss.

How can I achieve this in Excel? Please keep in mind that each result must be spread in 2 columns as shown above.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming this table:

[image]

Best result Team A:

```
=INDEX(B3:B8,SUMPRODUCT((B3:B8-D3:D8*1.01=MAX(B3:B8-D3:D8*1.01))*ROW(B3:B8))-ROW(B2))&" - "&INDEX(D3:D8,SUMPRODUCT((B3:B8-D3:D8*1.01=MAX(B3:B8-D3:D8*1.01))*ROW(B3:B8))-ROW(B2))
```

Worst result Team A:

```
=INDEX(B3:B8,SUMPRODUCT((B3:B8-D3:D8*1.01=MIN(B3:B8-D3:D8*1.01))*ROW(B3:B8))-ROW(B2))&" - "&INDEX(D3:D8,SUMPRODUCT((B3:B8-D3:D8*1.01=MIN(B3:B8-D3:D8*1.01))*ROW(B3:B8))-ROW(B2))
```

**How it works:**

Consider the function `SUMPRODUCT((B3:B8-D3:D8*1.01=MAX(B3:B8-D3:D8*1.01))*ROW(B3:B8))`.

When the column difference is equal to the max (or min for worst case) difference it will return one, otherwise it will return zero. The "*1.01" factor is the tie breaker. In case the goal difference is equal the tie breaker will favor the result with the least goals against, therefore returning only one max (or min).

The comparison result is then multiplied by the row number. Since we only have one "1" it will return the row number of the best (max) or worst (min) result.

Finally it uses the `INDEX` function to compose the score.

Comment: Thanks, this works perfectly. I am marking you answer as my accepted answer. Just one more question. This is not a final sheet so I will be adding new scores progressively. Will this formula work in that case too without having to change it every time? I tried it like this `=INDEX(B:B,SUMPRODUCT((B:B-D:D*1.01=MAX(B:B-D:D*1.01))*ROW(B:B)))&" - "&INDEX(D:D,SUMPRODUCT((B:B-D:D*1.01=MAX(B:B-D:D*1.01))*ROW(B:B)))` but its not working and I cant figure out why. I just tried to change it accordingly.

Comment: Updating my code (I dont have the second row with the GF GA text on my work sheet so my values start from B2 instead) to this one: `=INDEX(B:B,SUMPRODUCT((B:B-D:D*1.01=MAX(B:B-D:D*1.01))*ROW(B:B))-ROW(B1))&" - "&INDEX(D:D,SUMPRODUCT((B:B-D:D*1.01=MAX(B:B-D:D*1.01))*ROW(B:B))-ROW(B1))` but it wont work. Why? Is it strictly necessary to specify the last row?

Comment: You can create a Table for each team. Then, refer to the team ranges by table name. Tables will auto expand with new records.

Comment: If you refer to whole columns probably would work but row index calculation must be fixed. Using the whole column (witch I don't like) you don't need the `-Row(B1)` part since the INDEX function will also use the whole column.

Comment: By fixing index calculation you mean changing `=INDEX(B2:B8,` into `=INDEX(B:B,`? Or there is any other way?

Comment: I tried but I could not make it work with column references. However If you create a single Excel table with all the data (in my example it would be from A2:J8, and keep the formulas I provided, Excel will be smart enough to update them when new rows are inserted.

Comment: I tried too but the formula wont get updated automatically. You have to press the green corner of the cell and choose UPDATE. Seems like the formula wont work if one of the selected cells is empty and thats why it you cant choose the whole column. Is there any way around?

Answer (score 0):

Assume GF is in Column A & GA in Column C then in column D have formula

```
=IF(A3-C3>=0,A3-C3,0)
```

This will show non-zero positive integer value if Team A wins.

In column E have following formula.

```
=IF(C3-A3>=0,C3-A3,0)
```

This will show non-zero positive integer value if Team C wins.

```
Best Win -> =MAX(D3:D7)
Worst Loss -> =MAX(E3:E7)
```

Comment: I see. But this method will force me to ad the formulas every time I insert a new result, right?

Comment: Doesn't this answer give the VALUE of the best win / best loss columns, but not actually the total game (score of both sides) or perhaps the game row? In other words, it doesn't quite answer the question.